# Error make:*** [unit_test] in googleTest

Tags: c++, makefile, googletest

I have a project named Movies and I run some tests from googletest on it. I included the whole project and started running tests:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Counter.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


TEST(CodeTest, failTest)
{
Counter c;
EXPECT_EQ( 7, c.getValue() );
}

TEST(CodeTest, plusEqualsConstructor)
{
Counter f,g;
f=g+1;
EXPECT_FALSE(f==g);

}
```

and my main program is:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
RUN_ALL_TESTS();
return 0;
};
```

at first it worked as expected and then it gave me the following weird error:

```
make:*** [unit_test] Error 1
```

does anyone know what the problem can be? Thank you !!

Comment: Can you provide the makefile you're using?

Comment: I don't really know what my makefile means and how I find it.. sorry man.. can u explain or tell me how to find it?

Comment: If you get an error line that claims there is a `make` error, you are running `make` as part of your build process, hence you should be using a (maybe generated) `Makefile`. What is your development environment and build toolchain?

Comment: What are the errors listed *above* that `Error 1` line?

Comment: C++ build, my workspace is eclipse..
I have no errors above the first one